# Solr detects the language. How do I search now across multiple description_* fields?

Tags: search, solr, multilingual

I am trying to make multi-language stemming working with the Solr. I have setup language detection with `LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory` as per official Solr guides. The language is recognized and now I have a whole bunch of dynamic fields like:

- description_en
- description_de
- description_fr
- ...

which are properly stemmed.

The question now is how do I search across so many fields? Making a long query every time that will search across dozens possible language fields doesn't seem like a smart option. I have tried using `copyField` like:

`<copyField source="description_*" dest="text"/>`

but stemming is being lost in the `text` field when I do that.

The `text` field is defined as `solr.TextField` with `solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`. Maybe I am not setting up the `text` field properly or how is this supposed to be done?

Comment: See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields where it says:

`The original text is sent from the "source" field to the "dest" field, before any configured analyzers for the originating or destination field are invoked.`

copyField will not take the tokens from `description_*` fields after all the analysis is done. It will take the inputs to `description_*` fields and apply the analysis defined for its own field type, which is just the TextField with white space tokenizer in your case. So copyField is not a solution for this.

Comment: This may help you: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Query-on-all-dynamic-fields-or-wildcard-field-query-td4051852.html

Comment: Thank you, Arun. I see now why `copyField` didn't work. The second link is also very helpful. So I see that at this time my only choice is to list all the possible `description_[en|fr|de|...]` as list of fields to search on in each query. This is still ok I guess, I was just thinking that there were some other ways to do that. Thank you again for your help, Arun!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

1. search over all the fields you mentioned. There always will be some overhead: the more fields you use, the slower search will be (gradually)
2. try to recognise query language and search over only necessary fields: for example recognised and some default one. [Here you can find library for this](https://github.com/shuyo/language-detection/blob/wiki/ProjectHome.md)
3. develop custom solution with multiple languages in one field, which is possible and could work in production [according to Trey Graigner](http://www.treygrainger.com/posts/presentations/semantic-multilingual-strategies-in-lucenesolr/)

The question is a bit old, but maybe that answer will help other people.